# Avoid recursion in trigger - handling multiple triggers

Tags: trigger, recursion, boolean

I'm using this sample code from Developerforce to avoid recursion in triggers.

```
public class TriggerMonitor {

    private static boolean run = true;

    public static boolean runOnce() {
        if( run ) {
            run = false;
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return run;
        }
    }

}
```

I'm looking for ideas on how to adopt this to handle multiple triggers? If I go by this code, I'd have to create a distinct class to handle each trigger and that can get quite messy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I have used in the past:

```
public class TriggerControl {

    public static final String ENTITY_TASK = 'Task';
    public static final String ENTITY_ACCOUNT = 'Account';
    public static final String ENTITY_LEAD = 'Lead';

    @testVisible
    private static Map<String,Boolean> hasRunMap = new Map<String,Boolean>{
        ENTITY_TASK => false,
        ENTITY_ACCOUNT => false,
        ENTITY_LEAD => false

    };

    public static boolean hasRun(String entityType) {

        if (hasRunMap.containsKey(entityType)){
            Boolean hasRun = hasRunMap.get(entityType);
            if (!hasRun) {
                hasRunMap.put(entityType,true);
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }else {
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

It uses a map, which means it's quite extensible.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. It is exactly as I had envisioned - just that I couldn't put it down in code.

Answer (score 1):

One class will be enough, but one variable for each object at least. Also don't need to create a method for that, only need to make your variables public and it will do the job. Here is a good example.

```
    public class TriggerMonitor {

        public static boolean runAccount;
        public static boolean runOpportunity;
        public static boolean runContact;
    }

    trigger AccountTrigger on Account(.....){
        if (TriggerMonitor.runAccount == true) return;
    }

    trigger ContactTrigger on Contact(.....){

        if (TriggerMonitor.runContact == true) return;
        //....blablabla

        TriggerMonitor.runAccount = true;
        update accountList;
        TriggerMonitor.runAccount = false;
    }
```